# Boot of device is slow when previous connected wlan network is unavilable

Tags: wifi, linux, debian

My boot time increased if the connected wlan network is not available. If the connected network `random_rants` is not available it takes more time to boot.

My etc/network/interface configuration is:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless-essid random_rants
```

__

```
Listening on LPF/wlan0/0e:20:4e:a5:3d:0a
Sending on LPF/wlan0/0e:20:4e:a5:3d:0a
Sending on Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16
No DHCPOFFERS received.
```

Comment: This is because the interface waits for DHCPOFFERS. You can speed this up by using a static ip.

Comment: Actually I use my wifi in bot access point and client mode. During AP mode I set static IP. While client mode where I can connect other internet networks, in that I m using dhcp. Just changing static ip during client will reslove the problem ? or having a script at rc folder during boot up to set static IP ? I want to connect the previous connected network when I turn on the device. Does setting static IP will help ? thanks for the reply.

Comment: Others who face this problem I figured out the way actually. I used static IP during the pre-down and pre-up in order to avoid dhcp to stuck for 30seconds timeout till it finds the network. After using static IP boot time is normal as it was earlier. Ö.Ö

Answer (score 1):

This is because the interface waits for DHCPOFFERS. You can speed this up by using a static ip.